# Could not find the association problem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, models

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails, and I clearly have an active record association problem, but I can't solve it on my own.

Given the three model classes with their associations:

```
# application_form.rb
class ApplicationForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, :through => :form_questions
end

# question.rb
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
  has_many :application_forms, :through => :form_questions
end

# form_question.rb
class FormQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :application_form
  belongs_to :question_type
  has_many :answers, :through => :form_question_answers
end
```

But when I execute the controller to add questions to application forms, I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError in Application_forms#show

Showing app/views/application_forms/show.html.erb where line #9 raised:

Could not find the association :form_questions in model ApplicationForm
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In the ApplicationForm class, you need to specify ApplicationForms's relationship to 'form_questions'.  It doesn't know about it yet.  Anywhere you use the `:through`, you need to tell it where to find that record first.  Same problem with your other classes.

So

```
# application_form.rb
class ApplicationForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :form_questions
  has_many :questions, :through => :form_questions
end

# question.rb
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
  has_many :form_questions
  has_many :application_forms, :through => :form_questions
end

# form_question.rb
class FormQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :application_form
  belongs_to :question_type
  has_many :form_questions_answers
  has_many :answers, :through => :form_question_answers
end
```

That is assuming that's how you have it set up.

Comment: i've done this a thousand times and even when staring at my other working hmt models, couldn't see I was missing the other has_many...lol...

Answer (score 15):

You need to include a

```
has_many :form_question_answers
```

In your FormQuestion model.  The :through expects a table that's already been declared in the model.

Same goes for your other models -- you can't supply a `has_many :through` association until you've first declared the `has_many`

```
# application_form.rb
class ApplicationForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :form_questions
  has_many :questions, :through => :form_questions
end

# question.rb
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
  has_many :form_questions
  has_many :application_forms, :through => :form_questions
end

# form_question.rb
class FormQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :application_form
  belongs_to :question_type
  has_many :form_question_answers
  has_many :answers, :through => :form_question_answers
end
```

It looks like your schema might be a bit wonky, but the point is you always need to add the has_many for the join table first, then add the through.