# Ruby on Rails Devise Oauth-facebook OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, csrf, facebook-oauth

Im implementing oauth login with facebook and devise and When returning from accepting the app (the popup) i get the following error:

Could not authenticate you from Facebook because "Csrf detected".

this is the log:

> Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-23 23:59:58 +0100
>    ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
>   (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
>   (facebook) Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected

My user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :token_authenticatable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable,
     :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
    before_save :ensure_authentication_token

    has_one :user_settings
    has_many :predictions
    has_many :user_leagues
    has_many :leagues, through: :user_leagues # this wasn't working, solution found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781202/could-not-find-the-association-problem-in-rails

    valid_email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
     validates :email, format: { with: valid_email_regex }

    validates :firstName, :lastName, :username, presence:true
    acts_as_voter

    def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
      where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.firstName = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
        # user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
        user.save!
      end
    end
end
```

I have my facebook id and my secret in devise.rb

```
  require "omniauth-facebook"
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE if Rails.env.development?
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["APP_ID"], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
```

And i'm doing the verification through javascript

```
jQuery ->
  $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>')

  $.ajax
    url: "#{window.location.protocol}//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
    dataType: 'script'
    cache: true

window.fbAsyncInit = ->
  FB.init(appId: '123512341234', cookie: true)

  $('#sign_in').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    FB.login (response) ->
      #console.log(response)
      window.location = '/users/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse

  $('#sign_out').click (e) ->
    FB.getLoginStatus (response) ->
      FB.logout() if response.authResponse
    true
```

and a list of the gems in bundle install

```
rake (10.1.1)
i18n (0.6.9)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.8.4)
atomic (1.1.14)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
tzinfo (0.3.38)
activesupport (4.0.0)
builder (3.1.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
actionpack (4.0.0)
mime-types (1.25.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
treetop (1.4.15)
mail (2.5.4)
actionmailer (4.0.0)
activemodel (4.0.0)
active_model_serializers (0.8.1)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
arel (4.0.1)
activerecord (4.0.0)
acts_as_votable (0.8.0)
addressable (2.3.5)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
coderay (1.1.0)
better_errors (1.1.0)
sass (3.2.13)
bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.2)
mini_portile (0.5.2)
nokogiri (1.6.1)
xpath (2.0.0)
capybara (2.1.0)
certified (0.1.1)
ffi (1.9.3)
childprocess (0.4.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
execjs (2.0.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
thor (0.18.1)
railties (4.0.0)
coffee-rails (4.0.1)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
gherkin (2.12.2)
multi_test (0.0.3)
cucumber (1.3.10)
bundler (1.5.1)
hike (1.2.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
sprockets (2.10.1)
sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
rails (4.0.0)
cucumber-rails (1.4.0)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
warden (1.2.3)
devise (3.0.4)
launchy (2.4.2)
email_spec (1.5.0)
factory_girl (4.3.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.3.0)
faker (1.2.0)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
faraday (0.9.0)
hashie (2.0.5)
jbuilder (1.0.2)
jquery-rails (3.0.4)
json (1.8.1)
jwt (0.1.11)
multi_xml (0.5.5)
oauth2 (0.9.3)
omniauth (1.2.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.2)
omniauth-facebook (1.6.0)
pg (0.17.1)
rack-cors (0.2.9)
rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
rails_12factor (0.0.2)
rdoc (3.12.2)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
rspec-rails (2.13.1)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
sass-rails (4.0.1)
sdoc (0.3.20)
websocket (1.0.7)
selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
turbolinks (1.1.1)
uglifier (2.1.1)
```

Rails 4.0.0

Thanks a lot in advanced!

Comment: do we need to have the fb config twice 1. devise.rb and 2. omniauth.rb ?

Comment: No, if you are using devise, you only have to set it in devise.rb

Answer (score 18):

I added this to my app_name/config/initializers/devise.rb

```
{ provider_ignores_state: true }
```

so it ended up being

```
  require "omniauth-facebook"
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], provider_ignores_state: true
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: The explanation is that: 

"some OAuth2 providers ignore 'state' parameter, and don't return it back to the client. CSRF protection with this parameter is impossible for such services.

Add a boolean option :provider_ignores_state for disable CSRF protection for individual strategies."

Comment: This is dangerous.  It allows someone to attack your site using CSRF.  Your Gemfile doesn't list the version of omniauth-facebook you're using.  You should upgrade to 1.6.0.  Here is an example of how to use it with client side sign in: https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/blob/master/example/config.ru

Comment: I am having the same issue, but I can't find a workaround without ignore_state. Has anyone found a working solution with omniauth-facebook >= 1.4.1

Comment: any solution yet? i didnt have a problem with it until i integrated devise and omniauth-facebook

Comment: it would be d if sb would add an option to put the state param within the URL path, like /auth/:provider/callback/:state