# Many to many relationship ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Hi I'm trying to set up a many to many relationship in my app. I have two models `Count.rb`

```
class Count < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through: :counts_users
end
```

`users.rb`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :counts, through: :counts_users
end
```

and `counts_users.rb`:

```
class CountsUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :count
end
```

Now I can create a count

`Count.new(message: 'hello')`

but if I then do

`Count.last.users << User.last`

I get the error `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :counts_users in model ErrorCount`

I assume I've done something wrong setting up the association, but I'm not sure what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781202/could-not-find-the-association-problem-in-rails should point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your models' associations should be set up like this:

```
# count.rb
class Count < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :counts_users
  has_many :users, through: :counts_users
end

# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :counts_users
  has_many :counts, through: :counts_users
end

# counts_user.rb
class CountsUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :count
end
```

See: [the Rails Guides on has_many :through Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)